# How to make part of consecutive lines become a column of another part of consecutive lines?

Tags: notepad++, multiple-columns

Say I have a file:

```
The Rank Function
Permutations of Atoms
Pure Set Theory and Axiom System ZF
3.5
3.6
3.7
```

I want to move the last three lines to become another column of the first three lines, so the result would be:

```
3.5 The Rank Function
3.6 Permutations of Atoms
3.7 Pure Set Theory and Axiom System ZF
```

I'm not sure regex is the way since the number of lines is arbitrary.

Comment: What do mean by **the number of lines is arbitrary**? Very many lines but always available in sorted pairs?

Comment: yes. The number three in the example is just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> Left click on mouse and select the lines you want to move.
- Release the mouse button
- Left click on the highlight region and move it to the place you want.

Two options:

1. move the text after the numbers
2. move the numbers before the text

Comment: @Ooker: See official site of [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)